# Operator norm and Action

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, action

We define the norm of the operator as $\left\lVert A \right\rVert = \sup \frac{\left\lVert A\psi \right\rVert}{ \left\lVert A \right\rVert} = \sup \left\lVert A\psi \right\rVert$ for $A ∈ L(H)$. It is  said that $||A||$ measures the magnitude of the action of $A$.

What is meant by the action of $A$ and what is sup in this equation?

Also, how can we check if $A$ is bounded or unbounded with this statement?

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to enter mathematical expressions on Physics SE, as it is the site standard.  Images of text or equations are very strongly discouraged and can result in downvotes.

Comment: It is said where? Which page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operator is unbounded if its supremum norm is infinite. This follows trivially by negating the definition of a bounded operator in a preBanach space.

"A linear operator $A :D(A) \rightarrow X$ is called bounded, iff

$$\forall \psi\in D(A), \exists k\in \mathbb R, \text{so that} ||A\psi|| \leq k ||\psi||. $$

The maximum value of $k$ over the domain of A is called the supremum norm of A.

Answer (score 5):

The sup in the equation is a supremum over all states out of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. In other words, you pick the state $|\psi\rangle$ out of $\mathcal{H}$ for which the number $\frac{\mid\mid A|\psi\rangle\mid\mid}{\mid\mid |\psi\rangle\mid\mid}$ becomes the largest. It can be shown that the operator norm of $A$ corresponds to the largest eigenvalue of $\sqrt{A^{\dagger}A}$. As an operator acting on $\mathcal{H}$, $A$ maps one state out of it to another, which may be not normalized since you have no guarantee on $A$ being unitary. So you can think of the action of $A$ as a measure for “how much” non-normalized $A|\psi\rangle$ is, given that $|\psi\rangle$ is, i.e. $\langle\psi | \psi \rangle=1$.